# override bootstrap active/visited class on button

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-4, codepen

I'm trying to style the card header on a bootstrap 4 accordion, but I can't seem to override the preset class style.

I want to change `.btn-link` so that it is not underlined when active or when visited, but `.btn-link:active` and `.btn-link:visited` don't seem to change anything in the output, and I can't work out why.

Is it because I need to change the bootstrap css code itself? I'm doing this in CodePen so I don't have access to that from there.

If anyone has encountered this problem before, I'd be glad to hear from you!

Here is the link to the pen in CodePen: https://codepen.io/jreecebowman/full/dmpLRp/ (the accordion is in the 'products' section.

Otherwise, the code is below.

Thanks in advance!

html for the first card in the accordion:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </button>
  </h5>
</div>

<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion1">
  <div class="card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica...
  </div>
</div>
```

corresponding css:

```
#products {
padding-top:100px;
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
background-color:whitesmoke;
#accordion1, #accordion2 {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px lightgray;
    #headingOne {
        .btn-link {
            color:navy;
            opacity:0.8;
        }
        .btn-link:hover {
            opacity:1.0;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .btn-link:active {
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .btn-link:visited {
            text-decoration:none !important;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm fairly certain this isn't a css issue, as Collapsible group item 1 can be toggled from underline to no underline but does not work as intended. It seems the accordion does not toggle the active class properly for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just :hover and :active, you also have to add :focus

.btn-link:focus { text-decoration: none; }

try this:

```
#products {
padding-top:100px;
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
background-color:whitesmoke;
#accordion1, #accordion2 {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px lightgray;
    #headingOne {
        .btn-link {
            color:navy;
            opacity:0.8;
        }
        .btn-link:hover {
            opacity:1.0;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .btn-link:active {
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .btn-link:focus {
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .btn-link:visited {
            text-decoration:none !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and the fastest solution is to this. 
 `.btn-link:hover { text-decoration: none !important; }`
 I don't think it is a good practice to override Bootstrap classes, so the best idea is to create a new class and use the same code.